# Can't drag and drop behaviors in Expression Blend

Tags: windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop, expression-blend, behavior

When I start [Expression Blend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Blend) 4 (for [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) 7), I have all the behaviors (in the assets) loaded:

[image]

I want to add the `MouseDragElementBehavior` to a rectangle in my project.

But, as soon as I drag and drop the behavior on to the rectangle, all the behaviors "disappear":

[image]

My Expression Blend 4 version is 4.0.30816.0. Why is this problem occurring? I did a reinstall, but the problem persists.

Comment: Drag and drop is actually what Blend is designed for.  Don't be afraid to use it.  Just be aware of how it works and use it wisely.  (I always drag and drop onto the Objects and Timeline panel, never the artboard -- it's too easy to get the wrong target there.)

Comment: I agree with Mike, drag and drop is an essential part of your workflow  (In Blend).  If you want to work in XAML only, you could stay in Visual Studio.

Comment: Just wondering, if you type GoToStateAction in the search box, would the actual behavior appear?

Comment: another thing to notice, the Locations numbers are different on above two screenshots, which means the number of your total assets has changed...

Comment: Thanks @MikePost and Walt.. will keep that in mind.. Any leads to help me out here?

Comment: No clue, never seen this behavior (ha!) before.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to recreate this on my system but it worked correctly.  Can you verify the Blend version number?  Mine is 4.0.20901.0

In Blend I don't find drag and drop to necessarily be a bad practice.  There are areas where it can get you into trouble, such as data binding, and dropping visual elements on the screen will typically leave you with clean up work to do.  That being said, with behaviors I find drag and drop to be the preferred method of associating them with elements.

Comment: my Blend version is `4.0.30816.0`, is that the problem? can you give me a link for Blend `4.0.20901.0`

Comment: I'm using Blend 4.0.30816.0 and the MouseDragElementBehavior works as expected.

Comment: @Walt Oh, I hope this is not a localized issue with me.. there has to be something wrong.. have you heard of anything similar ?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. I did this solution:

1. Create your Windows Phone project in Visual Studio
2. In the folder 'References' from the Solution Explorer, right-click and select Add Reference...
3. In .NET tab, select the component "Microsoft.Expression.interactions"
4. Click Ok
5. Open this project in Blend
6. Try to add your behavior into an object in the TimeLine

Answer (score -1):

<s>I believe you cannot use Behaviors within a Windows Phone 7.0 project, only in a Windows Phone 7.1 project with Silverlight 4.</s>

Never mind, seems to work with a 7.0 project, too ...